# noise based dimming of an LED

Tags: led, analog, noise, dimming

I am thinking about building a dimmer for an LED that does not use PWM. My idea is to use a white-noise-signal and switch an LED on (or off) depending on whether the signal is above or below a certain threshold. The threshold can be changed thereby changing the average brightness.

Is that a feasible idea?

I want to have a signal that does not have any periodicity. Building a purely analog circuit would also make it faster and reduce detectable flickering (ideally). I believe it could also be more efficient.

The noise-signal is probably normally distributed. This means lowering the threshold would lower the average current non-linearily. This could increase the "resolution" for lower brightness values (which is often a problem with dimming LEDs).

If someone has some kind of survey about dimming methods for LEDs that address the problems of low frequencies and low resolution in areas of low brightness, I would love that!

Comment: Taking all of the energy that would be at a single PWM frequency and spreading it out while reduce visible flicker, especially on cameras. But why stop there? Take that energy and put it all at DC and you end up with a current dimmer that has no flicker at all.

Comment: It might have some advantages. Pretty easy to mock up a test and see what it looks like visually using a function generator and comparator.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but how about doing it digitally with a random number generator instead of analog white noise?

Comment: What @user1850479 said: If you already have a variable reference voltage, just send that to the LED!